# I am having an import error with the fitz library in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pymupdf

I am having this issue of importing the fitz library in PyCharm. I pip installed PyMuPDF and in my code I added "import fitz" but it is giving me this error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fitz/_fitz.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fitz/_fitz.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fitz/_fitz.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fitz/_fitz.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: are you using the same environment?

Comment: it is a environment problem, you should use the env which you install pymupdf in. please check in pycharm->settings -> python interpreter

Comment: How do I change it so that I can use the venv? Cause it shows that I have a venv environment setup but I am not to sure if I am using it.

Comment: Yeah so I just checked and it seems like I am using the right venv. But I am still getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this not working on my mac mini m2 chip was because there wasn't any wheel that supported it but there is a new wheel. Just use this in your terminal if you're having the same problem.

```
pip install --upgrade pymupdf
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using M1-macbook, hence this error `(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))`. Directly doing `pip install PyMuPDF` builds for 'x86_64' architecture. You need to build the `PyMuPDF` directly from the source release by the following:

- First install `mupdf`, `swig` and `freetype`

```
brew install mupdf swig freetype
```

- then install from the source:

```
pip install https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/archive/master.tar.gz
```

You can learn more from here:

- https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/discussions/1486
- https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/discussions/1704
- https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/discussions/1321